# Making CAPTCHA temporarily sticky for a user?

Tags: cookies, captcha, sticky

I've a forum where anonymous is allowed to post, protected by CAPTCHA. For users convenience, I set a Cookie for such a user which lasts about a month so the user does not get the CAPTCHA over and over again. In the simplest form the cookie is called `no_captcha_for_one_month` and it's value is `1`. When the user returns and posts anonymously, he gets not CAPTCHA.

Anyone seeing the flaw? A forum spammer just needs to fill out the CAPTCHA correctly once and use the cookie information for his bot and there he goes.

I thought about getting creative and using a server-side hash which includes e.g. users IP address and some secret salt to generate the cookie value, but it would still be valid for this IP address, of course.

Someone I get the impression the question is silly and I try to solve something unsolvable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with such a solution it is always possible to use the cookie for a bot. no matter what you try.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it underlines what I was thinking all the time: there's no real solution do it.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend implementing your cookie value + salt implementation not to solve your problem but for security reasons.  As explained by this [blog post](http://www.veracode.com/blog/2008/04/wordpress-25-cookie-forging-explained/) wordpress had a similar, albeit it much more severe, problem due to poor cookie security.  In your case a determined spammer could always bypass your CAPTCHA even if the cookie had expired.

In order to solve the proposed problem the only solution that is coming to my mind would be to implement a Forced CAPTCHA algorithm that would override your newly secured cookie if it felt the user was being spammy.  Off the top of my head I would use attributes like time since last post, number of posts today, the length of time it took to compose the message on the form, etc.

Edit:  I should also mention that you can make your forum less attractive to spammers in the first place by implementing the rel="nofollow" attribute on user submitted links.  See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nofollow).

Answer (score 0):

As said below, a cookie can easily be taken from a browser and pasted in a bot code, so the solution isn't robust.

Other solutions:

- Find some users posting a lot in the forum and ask them if they are volunteer to be moderator. A forum like the AutoHotkey one uses this system, and this works fine. Spammers tend to avoid active forums where moderation is fast and efficient. They prefer dead forums...
- Limit the number of anonymous posts per IP address. Can be annoying for users, but can avoid spam flooding. Should be set up only if you experience such flooding.

Answer (score 0):

Even worse, because you are using a cookie, the spammer doesn't even need to do the CAPTCHA once. Cookies can be changed by the client, they are sent by the browser with the page request, so the client can send whatever it wants. In fact spam requests would come from a script, so it's even easier to fabricate the cookies.

Storing the variable server side sill solve the problem I've mentioned; You set a random hash as the cookie, and have a table that stores the CAPTCHA status on the server. For the spammer to get no CAPTCHA, they would have to guess a hash that has the correct variable stored server side, shich is very hard to do.

The problem you mentioned; the fact that once a month might not be long enough to deter a spammer, you can't get around that. You have to show a CAPTCHA to every real user, as often as you want the spammer to enter one as well. Remember, a CAPTCHA is necessary because you can't tell a spammer from a normal user.

You should have the CAPTCHA show often, it will convince people to sign up anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Encrypt the time (in pico or nano seconds) set it as a input value () & set it in your DataBase with a column name 'hash'

set that in every page & see if it matches the DB.